# Type mismatch: cannot convert from View to ImageView

Tags: android, eclipse, image, casting, imageview

I tried to clean, open and close Eclipse, double check the id, double check R.java and I could not understand why this appears in the line

harryImageView = findViewById(R.id.harry);

What are possible solutions?

My code is:

```
 package com.example.imageview;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class ImageView extends ActionBarActivity {

    private ImageView harryImageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.image_view);

        harryImageView = findViewById(R.id.harry);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.image_view, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your layout file

Comment: Add image_view.xml to the quesiton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem here is that you class is called `ImageView` that is why you are having problems in your cast.

Try the following:

```
android.widget.ImageView harryImageView;
//...
harryImageView = (android.widget.ImageView) findViewById(R.id.harry);
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

`findViewById(R.id.harry)` returns a View Object, it does not recognize the type of the view it returns. You need to do the below:

`harryImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.harry);`

This way you tell the program to see the returned View as an ImageView object.

Comment: I did that, but even though the program was telling that it could not cast... It should show me a list of suggestions and one suggestion should be to cast, but they didn't suggest as expected.

Comment: This is the basic function of Java, not something the IDE provides :-) Also, please mark the answer as correct if you found it useful :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code if (ImageView) not work

```
(findViewById(R.id.harry) as ImageView)
```